# how to get total number of records from multiple records in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have run this below query

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(prim_key ,":" , 1) prim_key, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(prim_key ,":" , -1) urid, 
    CASE WHEN basicname = 'Q914'  THEN 'SHC'
         WHEN basicname = 'QP913'  THEN 'PHC'
         WHEN basicname = 'QC1214'  THEN 'CHC'
         WHEN basicname = 'QD1014'  THEN 'DH/SDH'
         ELSE 'UNKOWN' 
    END AS Status 
FROM facility_data 
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND basicname in ( 'Q914'  , 'QP913' , 'QC1214' , 'QD1014' ) 
    and prim_key like  '3_10_%' 
ORDER BY  prim_key ASC
```

I need to modify slightly, I want it to display total no of SHC , DH , PHC and CHC.

So please tell me what should i do to display Total no  of shc, dh,phc and chc.

Comment: Do you want the total or the total subject to the condition that `prim_key like  '3_10_%'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT status
     , Count(*)
FROM   (
        SELECT CASE basicname
                 WHEN 'Q914'   THEN 'SHC'
                 WHEN 'QP913'  THEN 'PHC'
                 WHEN 'QC1214' THEN 'CHC'
                 WHEN 'QD1014' THEN 'DH/SDH'
               END AS status
        FROM   facility_data 
        WHERE  basicname in ('Q914', 'QP913', 'QC1214', 'QD1014' )
        AND    prim_key like  '3_10_%'
       ) As x
GROUP
    BY status
```

If you want it grouped by `prim_key` and `urid` then

```
SELECT prim_key
     , urid
     , status
     , Count(*)
FROM   (
        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(prim_key, ':', +1) As prim_key
             , SUBSTRING_INDEX(prim_key, ':', -1) As urid
             , CASE basicname
                 WHEN 'Q914'   THEN 'SHC'
                 WHEN 'QP913'  THEN 'PHC'
                 WHEN 'QC1214' THEN 'CHC'
                 WHEN 'QD1014' THEN 'DH/SDH'
               END AS status
        FROM   facility_data 
        WHERE  basicname in ('Q914', 'QP913', 'QC1214', 'QD1014' )
        AND    prim_key like  '3_10_%'
       ) As x
GROUP
    BY prim_key
     , urid
     , status
```

Comment: Thanku so much i get the desirable result from first one.

Comment: @gvee the nested select is not necessary, because you can `group by` `basicname`. `status` is just a mapping from `basicname`  to `SHC , DH , PHC and CHC`. Probably mysql can optimized the nested select out, but it is always better to avoid them.

Comment: @t.niese I know it's not necessary but I thought that it was most illustrative for the Answerer :-)

Comment: @gvee I didn't check if it would or could have performance impacts, but because it is a `group by` on a result there is a probability that it is slower compered to a not nested select (Because mysql would need to first keep the result in a temporary space and then do a group on it. If it is not nested it can do the grouping while reading the rows). This for sure needs to be tested by the post of the question.

Comment: @t.niese I'm not that familiar with the internal workings of MySQL so am not best poised to comment. However in other DBMS systems (e.g. SQL Server) you can't refer to a calculated column's alias directly, so have to repeat the definition in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` with an `IF` statement inside if it is sufficient for you to get one row with just the counts (this you uses `where`).

```
 SELECT
     sum(if(basicname = 'Q914',1,0)) as SHC,
     sum(if(basicname = 'QP913',1,0)) as PHC,
     sum(if(basicname = 'QC1214',1,0)) as CHC,
     sum(if(basicname = 'QD1014',1,0)) as DH
 FROM facility_data 
 WHERE
     basicname in ( 'Q914'  , 'QP913' , 'QC1214' , 'QD1014' ) 
     and prim_key like  '3_10_%' 
 ORDER BY  prim_key ASC
```

or you use a  `GROUP BY` if you want to have multiple rows as result (requires `Using temporary; Using filesort`):

```
 SELECT
     CASE WHEN basicname = 'Q914'  THEN 'SHC'
          WHEN basicname = 'QP913'  THEN 'PHC'
          WHEN basicname = 'QC1214'  THEN 'CHC'
          WHEN basicname = 'QD1014'  THEN 'DH/SDH'
          ELSE 'UNKOWN' 
     END AS Status,
     COUNT(*) as `count`
 FROM facility_data 
 WHERE
     basicname in ( 'Q914'  , 'QP913' , 'QC1214' , 'QD1014' ) 
     and prim_key like  '3_10_%' 
 GROUP BY basicname
 ORDER BY  prim_key ASC
```

Comment: You should remove the `WHERE 1=1` condition.